# TFS - Specifying my own Editor when viewing a file

Tags: tfs

In TFS, I know I can specify my own tool for doing merges and compares. Can I also specify my own tool for viewing files? For example, when I am looking at Shelveset Details and click on a file and choose View, I'd like my own tool to display the file and not the default Notepad.

Randy

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: [TFS: How do I view .cs files in the VS IDE when viewing details of a shelveset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626476/tfs-how-do-i-view-cs-files-in-the-vs-ide-when-viewing-details-of-a-shelveset)