# when viewing details of a shelveset, when i double click the .cs or .sql files, why it opens in notepad?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, shelveset

i have gone through the [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626476/tfs-how-do-i-view-cs-files-in-the-vs-ide-when-viewing-details-of-a-shelveset) post and it says that the files take the automatic behavior of the windows to open the .cs and .sql files.

in my case when i open these files from a folder it opens up correctly in vs and sql server for .cs and .sql respectively.

Can anyone tell me how to open a file in a shelve in any editor other than notepad?

i have also checked the file types tab in folder options.

Comment: Better answers here, VS2008, but still relevant.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291881/when-viewing-details-of-a-shelveset-when-i-double-click-the-cs-or-sql-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the VS Shelveset Dialog which is modal - maybe that's the reason "they" designed the View function to spawn a new process of notepad. It's unfortunate because for some file types, the editor is not VS but it will still bring up notepad. This is consistent with all other TFS related operations in VS. with changesets, you can view files in VS or other editor, when you look at any non-modal dialog (history for a single file for example)
So unfortunately without hacking around there's no way to change this behavior.